# How to integrate AngularUI to AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Sorry for the silly question, does everyone know how to start using AngularUI? I've downloaded it from Github and read the instruction in README but still don't understand what I have to do.

Answer (score 63):

Steps to integrate:

- Include jQuery and jQuery-ui (best served from a CDN)
- Include angular (it is the best to include if from a CDN)
- Include angular-ui JS / CSS (currently only hosted in the GitHub repository in the `build` folder)
- Include any jQuery plugins for the directives you are planning to use
- Declare dependencies on the angular-ui modules (`ui.directives` or `ui.filters` depending on what you are planning to use).

Most of the outlined steps are just about including JS/CSS dependencies. The only "tricky" part is to declare dependencies on a ui.* module, you can do it like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.directives']);
```

Once all the dependencies are included and a module configured you are ready to go. For example, using the ui-date directive is as simple as (notice the `ui-date`):

```
<input name="dateField" ng-model="date" ui-date>
```

Here is the complete jsFiddle showing how to use the ui-date directive: http://jsfiddle.net/r7UJ2/11/

You might also want to have a look at the sources of the http://angular-ui.github.com/ where there are live examples off all the directives.

Comment: Actually, step 1 is optional depending on what directives you use and step 5 is just incorrect as only including `ui.directives` will throw errors when `ui.config` gets referenced.

Instead, you should always include `ui` and just remove the directives / filters you don't want.

Comment: Hmm, if I'm not mistaken step 5 is correct really since both `ui.directives` and `ui.filters` got dependency on the `ui.config` module. But sure, it could only mention the `ui` module.

Comment: Here is an example of integrating angular-ui, angular-strap, jquery, and a bit more - https://github.com/robertjchristian/angular-enterprise-seed

Comment: @martinpaulucci seems like the updated jsfiddle is also broken

Comment: Including jQuery will encourage DOM manipulation. It's not the end of the world but it may discourage you from solving problems in an angular way.

Comment: @RevNoah The directives from the original angular-ui repo, for which this answer was written, were wrapping jQuery / jQuery UI plugins, so you don't have an option. I mean, if you want to use those directives you have to include jQuery. Everyone agrees that avoiding jQuery is desirable for AngularJS apps, when can do without it, but if you can't - you can't. BTW, you can also write "bad AngularJS code" without including jQuery....

Comment: My mistake. Once again, I confused AngularUI with the more lightweight Angular UI Bootstrap library; not the first time. It's been a struggle avoiding jQuery but I've been successful so far. It's important to me but it might not be important enough to other developers. As I said, it's not the end of the world. One of the things I really love about Angular is how flexible it is, and how willing it is to let you break the "rules".

Comment: in nuget package manager : `PM> Install-Package Angular.UI` (for more information including determining dependencies here is the [nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Angular.UI/0.4.0) )

Answer (score 21):

As of 3rd of May 2013, here are the steps:

include

```
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

register ui

```
    angular.module('myFancyApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

make sure `myFancyApp` is the same as in your `<html ng-app="myFancyApp">`

Let the magic commence.

Comment: And as of now, use twitter-boostrap-css v2.3.1 or something similar and not v3.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. angular-ui-bootstrap and angular-ui are two different projects

Answer (score 11):

I think what is missing is plugins - you've got to add the jquery plugin scripts and css for some angular-ui directives to work. For example the codemirror directive needs:

```
    <script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/util/runmode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css" type="text/css" />
```

It's a surprise to me that angular-ui.github.com doesn't mention needing to include plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I wrote an article specifically on how to do this for for PHP syntax highlighting. The article is here: http://neverstopbuilding.net/how-to-integrate-codemirror-with-angular-ui/

The core of things is getting the configuration right:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui']);

myApp.value('ui.config', {
    codemirror: {
            mode: 'text/x-php',
        lineNumbers: true,
        matchBrackets: true
    }
});

function codeCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.code = '<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>';
}
```

For something like the following HTML snippet:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="codeCtrl">
        <textarea ui-codemirror ng-model="code"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the whole jsfiddle of the set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/jrobertfox/RHLfG/2/

pkozlowski.opensource is right, there are a lot more files that you need to include than it seems from the AngularUI documentation (if you can call it documentation...)

Comment: +1 for making me realize that I was injecting the wrong module. I was installing 'angular-ui' through bower and trying to inject 'ui.bootstrap'. Two separate things.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are in the readme.md file at their official github repository

[Angular UI](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)

Alternatively, the way you can find out how to integrate is to open the angular-ui js file (example: ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js) and in the first line, you will notice the following statement

```
angular.module("ui.bootstrap", [...deps...])
```

Based on the above code, you need to inject 'ui.bootstrap' into your module.

```
  angular.module('myFancyApp', ['ui.bootstrap','other_deps',.....]);
```

Comment: these are instructions for [Angular UI *Bootstrap*](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)