# Getting Angular UI to work

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angular-ui

I've just installed **Angular UI** and I'm having trouble to make it work. Here are the stepts I followed:

index.html (Angular v1.0.1, AngularUI v0.2.1)

```
<script src="scripts/vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/jquery-ui-1.8.18.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
var publicApp = angular.module('publicApp', ['ngResource', 'ui'])
```

my html

```
<input name="dateField" class="datepicker" value="Click Here for Datepicker" ui-date>
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object [[object HTMLInputElement]] has no method 'datepicker'
```

Using the JS console in chrome this works:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably could be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472244/

Comment: +1 for the question.  This was also plaguing me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you need to include jQuery *before* AngularJS / angular-ui files.
Here is the jsFiddle with the angular-ui date picker working: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/aGpNf/6/

Comment: This is probably the problem, I've previously run into the same gotcha.

Comment: I see an input field, but where is the calendar?