# Can't get the Angular-UI datepicker to work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Angular UI to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822862/getting-angular-ui-to-work)

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the datepicker example from the Angular-UI demo app to work. Does anyone have an example of a fiddle where the datepicker works (i.e. clicking on the input field pops up a calendar, etc.)?