# AngularUI integration - accessing module value from script

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have successfully integrated AngularUI into AngularJS application following instructions on stackoverflow ([How to integrate AngularUI to AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472244/how-to-integrate-angularui-to-angularjs)).

Now I am trying 'jQuery Passthrough' example from official AngularUI page.(http://angular-ui.github.io/).

```
<a title="Easiest. Binding. Ever!" ui-jq="tooltip">Hover over me for static Tooltip</a>

<a data-original-title="{{tooltip}}" ui-jq="tooltip">Fill the input for a dynamic Tooltip:</a>
<input type="text" ng-model="tooltip" placeholder="Tooltip Content">

<script>
    myModule.value('ui.config', {
    // The ui-jq directive namespace
    jq: {
       // The Tooltip namespace
       tooltip: {
           // Tooltip options. This object will be used as the defaults
           placement: 'right'
           }
       }
    });
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that 'myModule' variable (or whatever I try here) is not defined.
Without the script, the page is working (at least the static tooltip), so I guess AngularUI is correctly configured.

What should I do to access module variable?
Must this script be included into the controller class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're jumping ahead before you cover some basics. In order to code your application you need to declare a module.

Normally this is done by doing something like:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui']);
```

and then `myApp` becomes the contents of the `ng-app` attribute.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
angular.module('myApp').value('ui.config', { ...
```

if you do not wish to store a reference to the module in a variable. Keep in mind that storing the reference to a variable is the same as if you were to chain these calls on top of one another:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui']).value('ui.config', { ...
```

Any of these solutions should work for you

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. The problem was that the tutorial Angular project phonecat (https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat) was using requirejs. The globals have been declared later (when all scripts have been downloaded), therefor the app variable have not yet been available. I sovled this by wrapping the script code into 'define(['lib/jquery/jquery-ui'], function () {...});'

Comment: Hmmm.. I guess it is not working yet :/ I wrapped it into 'require(['lib/angular/angular'], function (angular)', received module and configured jQuery tooltip. However, I don't see any change if setting, for instance, track or placement attributes.