# Angular-UI ui-date component error "no method destroy"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I try to use the Angular-UI datepicker, but when i use the *ui-date* directive in my application code, i have this error : "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'destroy'"

I don't understand why !

Somebody can help me ?

My application dependencies (manage with bower) for information:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "*",
    "angular-mocks": "*",
    "angular-bootstrap": "*",
    "angular-ui-date": "*",
    "font-awesome": "*",
    "jquery": ">=1.8.2 <1.9.1",
    "jquery-ui": "*",
    "moment": "*",
    "moment-range": "*",
    "chardin.js": "*"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery *before* AngularJS scripts. Detail instructions for the step-by-step integration can be found in this question / answer: [How to integrate AngularUI to AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12472244/1418796)

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is a conflict with an another lib : 
https://github.com/Toodledo/ADE