# Download angular-ui

Tags: git, angularjs, angular-ui

It appears the makers of angular-ui are hell bent on leading everyone on a merry dance to discover the most relevant place to download their js files from.

- First I had a look on the angular [ui web
  site](http://angular-ui.github.io/).  No obvious download link
- Then I went to the [git hub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils),
  suggested using something called Bower?
- Then I noticed there was a download link from the [individual
  component link for
  validate](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/validate). This
  results in a 404
- Then I found [this
  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472244/how-to-integrate-angularui-to-angularjs)
  at last an actual download link! Oh no, two broken fiddles included
  in the answer!
  (Had to remove fiddles as *"it must be accompanied by code"* groan)
- Eventually the last fiddle in that
  question included a link that worked.

this links to http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js. Now I don't know if a) this is a legitimate mirror, b) this is the latest version.

So where on earth are you supposed to download this js file from? What is the official download link or do I need to use this Bower thing?

I guess they have obfuscated this process to stop people using them as a CDN but in the process they've made this considerably more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

#### cdnjs has an outdated version!

Looking here :https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui , I found this:

> DISCONTINUED REPO: This project has been restructured -> 
>   http://angular-ui.github.com/

The last version of angular-ui was **0.4** , but now it's discontinued.

They've just decided to break it down to separated modules ( which is great ).

I recommend using bower to install the modules you want, but you can also clone the repos.

Comment: Knowing it's been broken it into chunks does clarify the situation somewhat. The more I look at this the more the UI library feels unmature and in a state of flux. I think I'm going to back away from this particular piece of kit.

Comment: @Liam Does my answer addressed your question?