# Changing images on page (using hopefully angular) on a key being pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, angularjs

So, I have this array.

```
app.controller("ImagesController", function($scope){
    $scope.selectedImage = 0;
    $scope.images = [
        {
            image1: 'images/levels/level1/sky.jpg',
            image2: 'images/levels/level1/rain.jpg',
            image3: 'images/levels/level1/sky.jpg'
        },
        {
            image1: 'images/levels/level2/horse.jpg',
            image2: 'images/levels/level2/dog.jpg',
            image3: 'images/levels/level2/cat.jpg'
        }
    ];
```

I'll be adding more images to the array above.
I want three images to be on my html page at a time. Then as I press the right/left arrow key, I want the three images to get swapped for the next 3 images and so on(basically move the array to the next element I guess). Is this possible using AngularJS or Jquery? If it is, then how do I implement it?

EDIT: I'm okay with not using AngularJS as well and going for a simpler approach to changing the images, but I need that to happen fast.

Comment: Is this possible using AngularJS or Jquery? to answer your question, simply possible.

Comment: It sounds like you want something like - http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html , there are hundreds of js plugins available to do this sort of thing.

Comment: no need to overcomplicate it with properties `image1,image2,image3` , just use flat array. In angular change array and view changes

Comment: Dylan, I went to the website. That won't help and I want to make it myself anyway. 
charlietfl, Check the code again. I've updated it. Can't use flat array, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery for this.  You could tie it into an event like so using an index to select specific data "images" sets.

```
$('selector').keydown(function(key){
  if (key.keyCode == 'your desired key') {
      $scope.images[0..2];
 }
```

however you may want to rethink your array of images to better traverse through the sets in 3's like desired.

Answer (score 0):

rather than going jquery way... better to do it angular way... firstly you can use [angular ui's carousel directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel)..

its very simple to use, plus have lots of options

```
   <div style="height: 305px">
    <carousel interval="myInterval">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
          <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
```

in case you want to roll out your own implementation, you can do it using ui-keypress or ui-events directive available again at angular-ui, [link here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/keypress)

```
<input ui-event="{ blur : 'blurCallback($event)' }">

<script>
$scope.blurCallback = function(evt) {
alert('Goodbye. Input content is: ' + evt.target.value);
};
</script>
```

OR

```
<textarea
        ui-keypress="{13:'keypressCallback($event)'}">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Hi harish. Thank you for your answer but I am having trouble including angular-ui. I have already tried this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472244/how-to-integrate-angularui-to-angularjs

Comment: Harish I have successfully included angular-ui but the ui-keypress answer is not working. Please try to make it work locally and let me know if it works for you. What files do I include to make it work?

Comment: Can you setup a plunker.. Will check your plunker