# Still unable to include angular ui utils

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Hi i need to use the 'keypress' event from the angular ui utils library. But, I am unable to include angular ui in my project. I have already tried this- [How to integrate AngularUI to AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472244/how-to-integrate-angularui-to-angularjs)

Although, the jsfiddle posted in comments of that answer works, but it didn't work for me in sublime text. I can't understand why. I request someone to give a proper way to include angular ui and use ui-utils. Please try your method on a local text editor before posting answer.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle showing what you have so far?

Comment: I figured it out so I don't think there is any need for a fiddle anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out somehow! Add this code to your project:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Make a myApp.js file with the following code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.directives']);
```

The 'ui.directves' part can be changed for whatever you want to use. Eg. 'ui.events' (which I will be using).
Also, add

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
```

below all the links preferably. You're good to go!